# import sklearn.learning_curve fails in Python 3.3

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
sys.version = '3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
sklearn.__version__ = '0.15.1'
```

I have installed sklearn using the unofficial binaries at
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs or more specifically
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/4m3ocydo/scikit-learn-0.15.1.win-amd64-py3.3.exe

because pip install failed (missing compiler and packages)
When I import sklearn there is not error message but when I try to use it or import sklearn.learning_curve I get:

```
cannot import name inplace_column_scale
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\t-hanans\Apps\WinPython\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\learning_curve.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cross_validation import _check_cv
  File "C:\Users\t-hanans\Apps\WinPython\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .metrics.scorer import check_scoring
  File "C:\Users\t-hanans\Apps\WinPython\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .metrics import (accuracy_score,
  File "C:\Users\t-hanans\Apps\WinPython\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, label_binarize
  File "C:\Users\t-hanans\Apps\WinPython\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .data import Binarizer
  File "C:\Users\t-hanans\Apps\WinPython\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..utils.sparsefuncs import inplace_column_scale
ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale
```

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you did? You tried pip install sklearn, but pip install failed? Then you tried the binary packages?

Comment: I un-installed old sklearn and reinstall and now it works. Thanks Kyle.